# How to go to next input by tapping next key on an iPhone/iPad with Ionic1?

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, keyboard

keyboard didn't show next button to jump on next input field. I have tried this solution to do that but didn't work

```
 <div>        
    <input id="in" class="text-center col-33" type="number" ng-model="ngModel" ng-change="change()" (keyup.enter)="handleLogin()">
    </div>    


handleLogin() {
        e.preventDefault();
        var input = document.getElementById('in');
        input.focus();     
}
```

can any one have solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two or more input in form and you want the accessoryBar, add this:

```
Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false);
```

Then you should view the following:

[image]

With the cursors to go up and down.

Other thing if you want to change the input from the *(keyup.enter)=* then you should call the focus() function like I explain next.

Be sure in your config.xml you have this:

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

Then call the focus almost like you had done, this idea is [from @oroc](https://github.com/davidenke/angular-material-keyboard/issues/11#issuecomment-325745934):

```
.factory('focus', function($timeout, $window) {
  return function(id) {
  // timeout makes sure that is invoked after any other event has been triggered.
  // e.g. click events that need to run before the focus or
  // inputs elements that are in a disabled state but are enabled when those events
  // are triggered.
  var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
  $timeout(function() {
    if(element){
      element.focus();
    }
  });
 };
})
```

The key is call with timeout and test, some delay or call multiple times.

I call focus('') two times to avoid flickering (keyboard hide and then show in half of a second).

Comment: next button is not visible in keyboard can please tell me how to show next button